# Group by one column and sum the other

Tags: sql, postgresql

I this a query

```
SELECT * FROM user_state_logs WHERE user_state_logs.user_id = 1
AND created_at BETWEEN '2015-05-03 11:06:05' AND '2015-05-13 11:06:05'
```

That returns this

```
user_id   state   duration
1         call    10
1         call    20
1         wait    30
1         call    10
1         wait    20
```

I would like to return this

```
user_id   state   duration
1         call    40
1         wait    50
```

I've tried to adding a `GROUP BY user_state_logs.state`

But I get this error

> ERROR:  column "user_state_logs.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY
>   clause or  be used in an aggregate function

So two questions:

Why am i getting this error?

How could i get the query to return the data in the second format?

Comment: Actually, why total wait time 20, and not 50?

Comment: @Uriil it could be correct, if he wants to get overall call time and minimum wait time, that's what I've used in my answer. But it's better to wait for his comment

Comment: @urill Your right typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do it that way:

```
SELECT user_state_logs.state, user_state_logs.user_id, sum(user_state_logs.duration)  as duration
FROM user_state_logs 
WHERE user_state_logs.user_id = 1
AND created_at BETWEEN '2015-05-03 11:06:05' AND '2015-05-13 11:06:05'
GROUP BY user_state_logs.state, user_state_logs.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should group by `user_id` and `state`:

```
SELECT user_id, state, sum(duration)
WHERE user_state_logs.user_id = 1
   AND created_at BETWEEN '2015-05-03 11:06:05' AND '2015-05-13 11:06:05'
GROUP BY user_id, state
```

Answer (score 0):

You get error, because define select list when you use group by statement. Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, state, duration FROM user_state_logs 
WHERE user_state_logs.user_id = 1
AND created_at BETWEEN '2015-05-03 11:06:05' AND '2015-05-13 11:06:05'
GROUP BY user_id, state, duration
```

or

```
SELECT user_id, state, max(duration) FROM user_state_logs 
WHERE user_state_logs.user_id = 1
AND created_at BETWEEN '2015-05-03 11:06:05' AND '2015-05-13 11:06:05'
GROUP BY user_id, state
```